# how to count hyphenated words without using regex in python

Tags: python

hi i was wondering how to find the number of hyphenated words using dictionary(without using regex) in python? can anyone help ?

Comment: Could be as simple as `[x for x in paragraph.split(' ') if '-' in x]` or could be a complex. It depends on your situation.

Comment: What have you tried already so far?

Comment: Or even as simple as using `my_string.count('-')`, if your string wouldn't contain a hyphen in any other situation. This is if you really just need the number of hyphens, and not the hyphenated words themselves.